# Using one command line count the lines in the last file located in /etc in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, count, command, wc

ls /etc | tail -1  | wc -l

so basically I used this command but it counts the number of files that I've got from the tail command (which is the last file in the directory=1) but I didn't get the number of lines that are in the file.
and I used the cat command to open the file and count the lines but it didn't work.
ls /etc | cat tail -1  | wc -l
ls /etc | tail -1  | cat |wc -l

Comment: You should reward answer giver

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xargs` to use the result of the `tail` as an argument for `wc`, although I'd recommend using `find` instead of `ls` so you get the full path and don't need mess around with relative pathes:

```
$ find /etc -type f | tail -1 | xargs wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never parse `ls` (instead parse `/etc/*`)

```sh
$ wc -l < `find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -n 1`
```

or

```sh
$ find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -n 1 | wc -l
```

What this does is find the last file for /etc

And puts it's content in `wc -l`